# Accepting payment for bitcoins online: What types of payment "cards" or epayments are non-refundable?

Tags: payment, bitcoin-credit-card

I'd like to sell bitcoins to people online.  *My question is this*:

**What kinds of payments can I accept online that are *not* refundable, or charge-backable, *and* can somewhat easily be turned back into a local currency via international bank transfer or other?**

I know that PayPal, Credit cards, and Interac transfers can all be reversed. I've *heard* that things like UCash, are irreversible.... I'm new to this whole scene, and would like some informed input.

If possible, I'd like something that's available in both US and Canadian stores at a minimum, and is a "gift card" like solution that people can buy at Walmart, or their local grocery store, and could use to purchase something with me personally, or on a website. I'm flexible on almost everything except for losing payments due to chargebacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Western union online money in minutes. The client pays western union with their credit card, the client send you the mtcn, you pick up the funds. Pretty Much Irreversible.

Have you looked in to Green Dot Money Pak?
While not technically for payment processing, it is possible to send these to a merchant and they are non-refundable. FYI they are tracked by the federal government. Also always get a copy of their receipt and a signed waiver for anyone purchasing anything from you with a money pak.

There's a few companies that offer money pak conversion services or you could get a re-loadable card.

did i answer it thoroughly or do you need more information?

Comment: These are definitely some interesting suggestions! I'll take a look at them more closely over the new few days...

Comment: cool, if this is a godo answer please upvote it! There's a bunch of other ones too. (other card companies) You could request a walmart gift card or amazon giftcard as well. Giftcards are free to make with any coinstar machine.

*EDIT* Mastercard as rePower too which could be a solution. and other places have their own ones (i think walmart does for example)